# UILabel wont show the previous characters, only the last letter

Tags: ios, xcode, loops, label, nstimer

Goal is to enumerate every character in the String. That is 'w' will appear then after 1 sec will be replaced by 'h' then 'e' then 'n'.
Problem my label only shows the last letter.

What i did:
    1. drag a label and a button on the PlayViewController.
    2. create the property for Label
    3. create action for button

In my PlayViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PlayViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *listChar;

- (IBAction)startGame:(id)sender;

@end
```

In my PlayViewController.m:

```
#import "PlayViewController.h"

@interface PlayViewController ()

@end

@implementation PlayViewController

NSString *word;
NSTimer *myTimer;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.listChar.text = @" ";
    word = @"when";

}

- (IBAction)startGame:(id)sender {
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(listLetter:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


-(void) listLetter:(NSTimer*) myTimer {
    for(int i=0; i<[word length]; i++){
        unichar letter = [word characterAtIndex: i];
        self.listChar.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", letter];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know about why this happning then refer **@Nitin's** answer, and if you want to solve in other way then just use following code

```
-(void) listLetter:(NSTimer*) myTimer
    static int pos = 1;
    self.listChar.text = [word substringToIndex:pos];
    if (++pos > word.length) {
        [myTimer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again. Anyway I made some adjustment. my goal is only one letter will flash on the screen. User will only see w then w will be replaced by h and so on.                                                 - (void)listLetter:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    static int i = 0;
    unichar letter = [word characterAtIndex: i];
    self.listChar.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", letter];
    if (++i == word.length) {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}

Comment: then what is your problem ??

Comment: in your code, the whole word will be spelled. w will appear then wh then whe then when.  just made some adjustment, tnx again.

Comment: @user3266210 - you welcome - i putted code as per your requirement:) if any thing is wrong then plz tell me :)

Comment: after checking the question again, found out I wrongly formed the question. sorry for the confusion, my bad.